# Include only the users who haven't purchased from Woocommerce, SQL query

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to include only the users who havent purchased anything from current site. I can use this query to get the users who has purchased. But not sure how to do the opposit.

```
SELECT *
FROM {prefix}posts AS posts 
INNER JOIN {prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woocommerce_order_items ON posts.ID = woocommerce_order_items.order_id 
INNER JOIN {prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id 
INNER JOIN {prefix}postmeta AS postmeta ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id 
INNER JOIN {prefix}users AS users ON postmeta.meta_value = users.ID 
LEFT JOIN {prefix}usermeta AS usermeta ON users.ID = usermeta.user_id 


WHERE usermeta.meta_value = '%current_user_meta|client-name%'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM {prefix}usermeta WHERE user_id = users.ID AND meta_key = '{prefix}capabilities' AND meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%')
GROUP BY posts.ID;
```

Comment: can users have a post, when they have not ordered?

Answer (score 0):

As, you already have query to get the users who have purchased.

We can make use of left join to exclude these records to get the list of users who have not purchased.

```
   SELECT users.*
    FROM {prefix}users AS users
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT postmeta.meta_value
        FROM {prefix}posts
        INNER JOIN {prefix}woocommerce_order_items ON posts.ID = woocommerce_order_items.order_id 
        INNER JOIN {prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id 
        INNER JOIN {prefix}postmeta ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id 
        WHERE postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    ) AS users_who_purchased ON users.ID = users_who_purchased.meta_value
    WHERE users_who_purchased.meta_value IS NULL
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM {prefix}usermeta WHERE user_id = users.ID AND meta_key = '{prefix}capabilities' AND meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%');
```